# Getting all the master nodes in an elasticsearch cluster

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I am trying to get all the master nodes in an elasticsearch cluster using this code. Can I reduce/simply this or optimize further?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'elasticsearch'


client_node = ARGV[0]

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: client_node

clients = client.nodes.info process: true

clients['nodes'].each do |node|
        node_id = node[0]
        puts clients['nodes'][node_id]['host'] if clients['nodes'][node_id]['attributes']['master']== "true"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Fix your indentation. Ruby uses 2 spaces of indentation.
2. Your naming is confusing. You have `client_node`, `client` and `clients`, which are all very different things (string, object, hash as far as I can tell). The only one that's well-named is `client` since that is indeed an instance of `Client`. But `client_node` you can skip entirely since you can just as well write `ARGV.first` (which is more Rubyesque than `[0]`) in the one place you need it. Or you can call it `host` since that what it is. And `clients` could be called `client_info` or something similar. Name it for what it is.

   **Note:** In the following I keep your names for simplicity's sake, but you should really reconsider the naming in your code.
3. You can iterate keys *and* values in loops:

   ```
   clients['nodes'].each do |name, info|
     puts info['host'] if info['attributes']['master'] == "true"
   end
   ```
4. Things will break if the info hash doesn't have an `attributes` key - your code is assuming it's there. A way to avoid this is to use `Hash#fetch` to absorb nil values:

   ```
   puts info['host'] if info.fetch('attributes', {})['master'] == 'true'
   ```
5. Since all you want is the `master` node, it'd be more expressive to find that node first - if it exists - and then do what you want with it:

   ```
   master_node = clients['nodes'].detect do |name, info|
     info.fetch('attributes', {})['master'] == 'true'
   end

   puts master_node['host'] if master_node
   ```

Beyond that, I feel confident the Elasticsearch library exposes a bunch of convenience methods you can use instead of accessing values with string keys. There may also be a way to fetch just the `master` node, instead of looping through stuff to find it. But I don't know the library, so it's just a guess.